# Return value pairs based on first row and column

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, gnumeric

Gnumeric has a nice tool for calculating correlations, but is limited in terms of specifying your output. It looks like [this](Https://help.gnome.org/users/gnumeric/stable/descriptive_statistics.html.en#correlation-tool), Figure 8-7 :

```
Correlations | pressure | distance | height
pressure     |        1 |          |
distance     | 0.9841073|        1 |
height       | 0.7633996| 0.7239509|      1
```

I would like to generate pairs like this:

```
pressure pressure  1
pressure distance  -
pressure height    -
distance pressure  0.9841073
distance distance  1
distance height    -
height pressure    0.7633996
height distance    0.7239509
height height      1
```

I'm fine with 1's and blanks, but it would be nice if I could avoid them. It doesn't have to be within a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward `Index/Match`:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($A6,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH($B6,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

Assuming your data is like the below:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in Excel 2010 or Gnumeric (I know to substitute commas with semicolons with it).

Comment: @anon8723879278 - This should work in Excel 2010...what happens when you try to use it?

Comment: "Circular reference warning"

Comment: @anon8723879278 - How is your worksheet setup? That warning means you're referencing the cell the formula is actually in.  In my example, I put the formula in `C6`.  You will likely need to adjust yours.  This formula will work in Excel 2010, it's just you need to tweak the ranges to match your data.

Comment: It works when I input the variable names in preceding cells. Part of my question was about automatically generating these "pressure pressure, pressure distance" pairs. I apologise for not making that clear enough.

Comment: @anon8723879278 - Oh I see.  That'd be a separate question, the one you asked here was primarily how to get the values out of the table.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1310460/generate-cell-pairs-based-on-first-row-and-column