# Generate cell pairs based on first row and column

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

Given a spreadsheet like this:

```
x | pressure | distance | height
pressure
distance
height
```

I would like an output like this:

```
pressure pressure
pressure distance
pressure height
distance pressure
distance distance
distance height
height pressure
height distance
height height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in A1,

Then in C1 enter the below as an array formula, hold CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER after entering

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$A$3,CEILING(ROWS($B$1:B1)/(SUM(1/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$3,$A$1:$A$3))),1),1)}
```

then in D1 enter the below:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$3,COUNTIF($C$1:C1,C1),1)
```

Then drag them both down until you get a REF error in column C.

Change `$A$1:$A$3` in both formulas to suit your range of original data.

Comment: In my use case A1 is empty and B1:D1 and A2:A4 are used. Tweaking your solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @anon8723879278 - In, say cell `A6`, use this: `=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,CEILING(ROWS($B$1:B1)/(SUM(1/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$4,$A$2:$A$4))),1),1)` (enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, and drag down).  Then in `B6` enter this and drag down: `=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,COUNTIF($A$6:A6,A6),1)`